# haproxy and large GET requests

Tags: haproxy

I have a server that needs to receive large (64K) GET requests.  It looks like haproxy (v 1.6) has a compile-time limit of 16K.  I'm hoping I missed something.

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#3.2-tune.bufsize

Any pointers other than recompiling haproxy?

Somewhat related, any insight why haproxy would return 400 and not 414 in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can provide an answer to the primary question.  Despite the linked documentation, this appears not to be a compile-time option.  It was enough to set

```
tune.bufsize 65536
```

in the global section of `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`.

As to 400 vs 418, this was my own bias.  HAProxy is saying that the request is too long, which is included in 400.  I was thinking of GET requests in which the URI itself is too long (418), and this is a subset of the request itself being too long.