# HAProxy URL length limit

Tags: url, get, haproxy

I have an application which makes GET request of length 18k characters. If this requests goes through HAProxy then I get immediately 400. If I hit directly my service everything is fine. Is there a parameter in HAProxy which sets maximum length of URL request in HAProxy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [haproxy and large GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090720/haproxy-and-large-get-requests)