# HAProxy returns 414 Error Code with very long URL

Tags: haproxy

I made GET request with very long URL (size 12k) to Haproxy server and got 400 Bad request. Then i set

`tune.bufsize 65536`

as suggested here: [haproxy and large GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090720/haproxy-and-large-get-requests).

Now server return  `414 Request-URI Too Long.`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have also to increase the servers request uri length.

For example for nginx https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430750/6778826

Comment: Thanks, Aleksandar, but same result .  I saved my URL to txt file , and size is 9063 bytes. Then i cut some chars from url and find out that if size is around 8.3 KByte  the url is worked. It seems there is some default parameter with 8 Kbyte value